# How to Dynamically Create Formal Arguments from a DataFrame of Argument Values (R)

Tags: r

I have a dataframe of values that I would like to use to build arguments to later send to a separate function, myFunction(name, size, nationality). E.g.

```
name <- c("Batman", "Superman", "HeMan")
size <- c("Med", "Tall", "Enormous")
nationality <- c("American", "Kryptonian", "Eternian")
argVals <- data.frame(name, size, nationality)
```

Note, each column has an appropriate name that I'd like to use as the name of the argument later to be passed to myFunction, which expects each of those formal arguments.

I'm not sure if I should create a string that I later pass to myFunction:

e.g. "name='Superman', size='Med', nationality='American'"

Or, if I can find a way to directly pass the names values to myFunction.

I've tried using various incantations of paste, but I'm thinking there must be an easier way. Thanks.

Note: edited to emphasize my lack of clarity on the appropriate way to call functions with named values.

Comment: are you looking for `?do.call` ?

Comment: You plan to pass a string with parameters to an R function? Because that's not how R functions generally work.

Comment: do.call is the closest I've gotten. If I do, do.call(paste, argVals), I get an answer with the right dimensions, but it's just the values (not the colName1 = value1, colName2 = value2 format I need). Would you recommend creating my own variation of paste and sending that into do.call? Thanks.

Comment: @Rocinante My solution was based on the expected result you showed.  If you didn't wanted to paste, you should have showed in the post

Comment: @akrun, you're result showed the correct paste formulation (and very quickly!). My apologies - I didn't know that do.call would accomplish the entire function call with the named arguments. As I'm still learning R I didn't formulate my question as well as I should have. I edited to make this clear to future readers. Thanks.

Comment: @Rocinante It is okay.  Now, I understand that you wanted a key/value combiantion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` to prevent the elements of `argVals` from getting turned into factors:

```
argVals <- data.frame(name, size, nationality,
                        stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

then

```
as.list(argVals[1,])
## $name
## [1] "Batman"
## $size
## [1] "Med"
## $nationality
## [1] "American"
```

will generate a named list with the appropriate values, which is probably what you want.  (Alternatively you can use `lapply(as.list(argVals[1,]),as.character)`, but it's probably simpler/clearer to stop the columns from getting made into factors in the first place.) If you have a function `foo(name,size,nationality)` then `do.call(foo,argVals[1,])` will run the function with the specified arguments.

Comment: Thank you @BenBolker  - the do.call(foo, argVals[1,]) approach you mention works great.